# Can the 'cat' command be used to concatenate or merge multiple vcf files into one?

Tags: command-line

Will doing so overwrite my original files?

Answer (score 2):

If with vcf files you mean vCard files, the resulting file works with OS X's Address Book. My guess is that it should work with any application.

If you do it with `cat *.vcf > all.vcf`, you will not overwrite your original files.

Comment: I confirm that the above works (without destroying original files), yielding a single vcf file that was successfully imported in Thunderbird. In contrast, the vcf-concat package did not work for me, complaining of "broken VCF headers".

Answer (score 1):

There is no sense to use `cat` (`cat` is useful for text based files) since there is [VCFtools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vcftools/). To install it from terminal, use:

```
sudo apt-get install vcftools
```

Then you can concatenate VCF files using `vcf-concat`. See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/vcf-concat.1.html